# PHP json_encode returns List of objects, flutter json.decode doesn't recognize response data as valid json

Tags: php, json, flutter

I'm having issues decoding json response data in flutter.

1. My .php file gets served to the [Live Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtlGT.png) as a List Object (after json_encode())
2. When I [view the source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XmRZc.png) it shows [valid json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Isczs.png), which i've validated on [jsonlint](https://jsonlint.com/)
3. Trying to decode the response on flutter returns an error, recognizing the response as List and not a JSON String

puzzled at this point on what to do.
Would appreciate your help

```
config.php

<?php
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASS', '');
define('DB_NAME', '');


// create connection
$conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
$is_utf_8 = $conn->set_charset("utf8");

// check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die('Connection Failed ' . $conn->connect_error);
}

fetch_users.php

<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
header('Accept: application/json');
header('Allow: GET');
include 'config.php';

$sql = "SELECT * FROM Users";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

$list = array();
while ($rows = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $list[] = $rows;
}
echo json_encode($list);
```

Comment: "recognizing the response as List and not a JSON String" -- that sounds as if the response has already been decoded to an array of objects and you're trying to decode it twice. Could that be the case?

Comment: Yeah I think that was the case. In my flutter method I completely abandoned the "var response = json.decode(response.data)" and instead assigned the variable directly to "var response = response.data". Not sure if it's a Dio package error, but it was unnecessarily frustrating.